# Nodejs ZMQ monitoring sockets

Tags: node.js, sockets, monitoring, zeromq, monitor

I got this code for monitoring sockets in the zmq bindings for nodejs. So far it works but my problem is I dnt know what events the monitoring socket has. The code I got only did that, I will continue looking for more code but this is what I have so far..
``

```
var zmq = require('zmq');
var socket = zmq.socket('pub');
socket.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:10001');
socket.monitor();
```

I tried adding an "onmessage" event handler but it showed nothing, so.. I dnt know whats up..

```
socket.on("message",function(msg){
    console.log(msg);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I printed the object that I got back from the monitor() function and from it I was able to get some monitor events, I think it is unelegant though, I got this link that tests the monitor function of the socket ( https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node/blob/master/test/socket.monitor.js ) but some things are not working but...

```
mon.monitor();
console.log(mon);
mon.on("message",function(msg){
    console.log(msg);
});
mon.on('close',function(){console.log("Closed");});
mon._zmq.onMonitorEvent = function(evt){
    if (evt == 1)
        console.log("Should be 1 : "+ evt);
    else
        console.log(evt);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with the PUB/SUB handlers in 0mq.  I have used some of the other types and am fairly familiar.  Having not tested this code, my recommendation would be

SCRIPT 1: Your existing PUB script, needs to send a message

```
  socket.send('TEST_MESSAGES', 'BLAH')
```

SCRIPT 2: This needs to be added:

```
var zmq = require('zmq');
var sub_socket = zmq.socket('sub');
sub_socket.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:10001');
sub_socket.subscribe('TEST_MESSAGES')
sub_socket.on("message",function(msg){
    console.log(msg);
});
```

The trick here is timing.  0mq doesn't give you retries or durable messages.  You need to build those elements on your own.  Still if you put your publish in a timer (for the sake of getting an example running) you should see the messages move.

Comment: So I am not looking to get message events.. I want to get events from the onMonitorEvent added after monitor() is called on the pub socket. I managed to make a hack but it is definately not elegant, I am looking through some of the sample code that the git owner had but some of his scripts are not working.. :(       mon.monitor();
console.log(mon);
mon.on("message",function(msg){
 console.log(msg);
});
mon.on('close',function(){console.log("Closed");});
mon._zmq.onMonitorEvent = function(evt){
 if (evt == 1)
  console.log("Should be 1 : "+ evt);
 else
  console.log(evt);
};